# Как переписать запрос с msql на yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Делаю фильтр, нужно сделать вот такой запрос через QueryTrait.

```
SELECT * FROM attributes 
WHERE (attributes.count_room BETWEEN 5 AND 999 OR attributes.count_room IN ('1', '5'))`
```

Не понимаю как скомбинировать AND и OR именно в скобках, (чтобы не перекрывало другие фильтры, когда выполняется OR)

Comment: Решил. Кому надо -  `$query->andFilterWhere([
            'or',
            ['between', 'attributes.count_room', 5, 999],
            ['attributes.count_room' => $this->count_room],
        ]);`

Answer (score 0):

Решил. Кому надо - `$query->andFilterWhere([ 'or', ['between', 'attributes.count_room', 5, 999], ['attributes.count_room' => $this->count_room], ]);`